# Create Complex method body dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I have a requirement that i want to create a class with a method dynamically which will take few argument and return some value. But my method must have one logic i.e Inside my method it will create the instance of another class and call one of the specific method of tha.

e.g
Below is the class that what i want to create.

```
public class Test 
{    
    public object NewMethod(Type ClassType, object[] Data)
    {
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(ClassType, Data);
        MethodInfo m = ClassType.GetMethod('MessageGenerator');
        return m.Invoke(obj, Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Test class has to be created at runtime may be by using Reflection.Emit

Comment: Creating *types* at runtime is relatively complex - you end up having to use `TypeBuilder`, which is non-trivial; how many methods do you need? For example, could you use a *single* type with a delegate member that is basically `Func<object[],object>`? then you can use the expression-tree API. Alternatively: how heavily is this going to be used? Would your existing reflection implementation suffice?

Comment: "Test class has to be created at runtime may be by using Reflection.Emit" - why does it? what's the reason for that?

Comment: We are not here to convert your code to _Reflection Emit_.  Have you tried it yourself?   You might want to look at _CodeDOM_.  Much easier

Comment: This is not to convert my all code to Reflection Emit. But it is something very similar to AOP. More closely you can say AOP Around Advice.

Comment: AOP is a concept not an implementation technology

Answer (score -1):

Strong Typisation is your greatest friend. Do not try to get around it. If you want to see what a langauge with weak Typisation looks like, take the JavaScript and PHP examples from this Comic:
http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/

If the method is a simple "Multiple chocie" thing, Delegates are the way to go. They are half the magic behind Events. 
Otehrwise there is full support for functions generated [entirely at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-and-execute-dynamic-methods). But as other said, this is not trivial.

As for dynamic types:

One way is the keyword dynamic, but my advise is to stay clear of that one unless you **really** need it. It moves all type checks to the runtime. Moreover dynamic works a bit like a infectous diseases: Any variable that was used with a dynamic one, becomes dynamic itself. Even the return values of functions can be altered to dynamic just by handing a dynamic value as one of the arguments.

If this is mostly about storing data from a WebService call, there is a stable helper: [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.7.2). It seems to be little more then some Syntax Sugar on a Dictionary. But it certainly helps store data until you can translate it to a proper, predefiend .NET Class.